# Block remote desktop connection for local users

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, mstsc, applocker

I have windows 2012 server r2 machine with local users only. Machine is not part of any domain. I want members of "users" group to be restricted to use mstsc.exe / remote desktop connection from this machine to any other.

I tried blocking outbound ports 3389 for TCP/UDP in windows firewall and used Applocker to create a rule to block mstsc.exe for "users" gp members but users can still mstsc from this machine successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried deleting mstsc.exe?

Comment: In our environment, users can copy paste mstsc.exe